# Hive connection fails

Tags: hive, fiware-cosmos

I'm trying connect to Hive in the public Cosmos instance and it fails.

When I try to get the connection by the DriverManager in Java fails. It gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open connection to jdbc:hive2://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:206)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:178)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at com.isetic.cosmos.HiveConnectorTest.main(HiveConnectorTest.java:29)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:248)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:203)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
... 8 more
```

So I decide to connect with my user in Cosmos instance and then try to launch Hive server and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /tmp/hadoop-user
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.ensureDirectory(RunJar.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:144)
```

So what is wrong with Hive??

It works some weeks before and the code have not been changed, so I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an environment issue, probably hive server 2 is down. Check its health by log in into the server node and see the status of Java processes.